# Change string in SQL Server to abbreviate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I return the everything in a string from a sql query before a certain character?

My data looks like this:

```
HD TV HM45VM - HDTV widescreen television set with 45" lcd
```

I want to limit or truncate the string to include everything before the dash.

So the final result would be "HD TV HM45VM"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx), but you'll have to use either [CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) or [PATINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) to get the location of the character you want the substring to stop at:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('HD TV HM45VM - HDTV widescreen television set with 45" lcd', 
                  0, 
                  CHARINDEX('-', 'HD TV HM45VM - HDTV widescreen television set with 45" lcd'))
```

To do the opposite - strip everything to the left of the hyphen - use:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('HD TV HM45VM - HDTV widescreen television set with 45" lcd', 
                  CHARINDEX('-', 'HD TV HM45VM - HDTV widescreen television set with 45" lcd') + 1,
                  LEN('HD TV HM45VM - HDTV widescreen television set with 45" lcd'))
```

Effectively, make the location of the hyphen to be the starting point.  Then you can use either `LEN` or `DATALENGTH` functions.

Comment: You might need to trim spaces afterwards - look at using LTRIM or RTRIM if that's the case.

Comment: Does the trick. Thanks a bunch. How would I do do the opposite? How could I strip everything to left of the dash?

Comment: I recommend LEN(). DATALENGTH() will fail if the OP either now or later plans to use `nvarchar`. Also, if the field is `varchar(1000)`, you can simply provide 1000 as the third argument to SUBSTRING() and avoid the LEN() call.

Comment: @jeff: Forgot the comma - try now.

Answer (score 2):

Dont forget that LEFT exists

```
select LEFT('HD TV HM45VM - HDTV widescreen television set with 45" lcd',CHARINDEX('-', 'HD TV HM45VM - HDTV widescreen television set with 45" lcd ')-1)
```

Comment: Upvoted for using LEFT() rather than SUBSTRING() (a better fit IMHO for readability), but you should substract 2 rather than 1. CHARINDEX() is 1-based and you only searched for the dash, not the preceding space.

Comment: True, but will the space be there, then rahter use a **RTRIM**

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll take a stab at it too and see if I can simplify:

```
SELECT LEFT(myfield', CHARINDEX(' - ', myfield) - 1)
```

By wrapping the `-` in spaces, the delimiter is less likely to be tripped up, and there's no need to trim the result.

Caveat: this, like the other responses, will result in an error if `myfield` does not include the `-` delimiter.

Ultimately, if there is *always* a dashed delimiter in your table, you should consider having two fields.

Comment: astander brings up a good point - PATINDEX would be a better choice for that, because it allows psuedo-regexes

Comment: @astander - where do you get that from the OP? Also, while PATINDEX() allows use of wildcards, it isn't capable of expressions like "an optional *space*, followed by a dash". CHARINDEX() will perform better given the input data provided. Searching for the space will avoid an edge-case bug that is entirely likely if the first portion of the string contains a dash (since many product codes in the wild may contain dashes, but not usually prefixed by a space). If the data are all delimited consistently, string parsing should exploit the more robust delimiter to avoid false positive splits.